# Launch Oracle stored-procedure in Java code

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I wrote a stored-procedure in Oracle and now, I want to launch it in Java code.
I will describe a problem. I have a object type:

```
TYPE PERSON_TYPE AS OBJECT (ID NUMBER(38), NAME VARCHAR2(20));
```

And table type:

```
TYPE PERSON_TYPE_TABLE AS TABLE OF PERSON_TYPE;
```

My procedure looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE EVALUATE_PERSON_PROC(P_PERSON_ID IN NUMBER, return_data OUT NOCOPY PERSON_TYPE_TABLE) 
AS
--Some code
BEGIN
--Some code
END;
```

How to launch this procedure in Java code? Which classes are the best to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [CallableStatement class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html):

```
String sql = "{call EVALUATE_PERSON_PROC(?, ?)}";
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
...
statement.execute();
```

Comment: +1. I also suspect the author will need some documentation on returning table types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031420/returning-a-table-type-from-a-plsql-function-called-via-jdbc

Comment: Yes, I know it. But what doing with my type which I created in PL/SQL?
How to configure CallableStatement that return collection of my type?

Answer (score 8):

Why not use [Spring's DAO abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) (a very useful and reasonably lightweight **library** around raw JDBC which eliminates the need for boilerplate code) you can subclass the `StoredProcedure` class.

```
class MySproc extends StoredProcedure {
    public MySproc(DataSource ds) {
       super(" { exec MY_SPROC ?, ? }", ds);
       declare(new SqlParameter("p1", Types.VARCHAR));
       declare(new SqlParameter("p2", Types.INT));
    }

    public void execute(String p1, int p2) {
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("p1", p1);
        m.put("p2", p2);
        super.execute(m);
    }
}
```

Then this is executed very simply as follows:

```
new MySproc(ds).execute("Hello", 12);
```

With no database `Connection`s, `CallableStatement`s anywhere to be seen. Lovely! Oh yes, and it also provides annotation-based `Transaction`s.

If your sproc returns a table, this is incredibly easy using Spring. Simply declare:

```
       declare(new SqlReturnResultSet("rs", mapper));
```

Where `mapper` is an instance that converts a line of a `ResultSet` into the desired object. Then modify your line:

```
        Map out = super.execute(m);
        return (Collection) out.get("rs");
```

The returned `Collection` will contain instances of objects created by your `mapper` implementation.

Comment: probably for statement like this, introducing spring libraries into project is nonsense. There is also scenario where this author could decide to deploy code directly to Oracle DBMS, where spring would make a lot of pain.